# tableview won't scroll to bottom in landscape in swift

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview, landscape, portrait

I am using

```
 if myArray.count >  1 {

                self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: myArray.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
            }
```

This sets my portrait view to the bottom of the table.  But it does not work in landscape view.  Orientation is set to all
            portrait
            upsidedown
            landcape left
            and landscape right
If only landscape modes are set the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you start your app in landscape mode?

Comment: Orientation is set to all portrait upsidedown landcape left and landscape right If only landscape modes are set the problem still exists.

Comment: Where is the code? viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear etc?

Comment: Both viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear. However, I resized the tableView to give more room to the search controller and removed a footer (replacing with a label so results would always be at the bottom ) and the tableview is working the way it should now.